# Access control values from a module vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need to access textbox values that are in Form1 from Module1 in my VB.net program.  I thought I read somewhere that you can make your controls Public and then you can access the values.  I tried this but it does not work.  What do I need to do?

Here is my code:

```
    Module Module1
    Dim connectionMaster = New ConnectionMaster()
    Dim uname As String
    Dim pw As String

    Dim frmInstance As Form2
    frmInstance = New Form2
    uname = frmInstance.Username
    pw = frmInstance.Password
```

Username and Password are in Form2.  When I try to build this, I get the error message "Value of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' cannot be converted to 'String'"

I changed the above to:

```
uname = frmInstance.Username.text
pw = frmInstance.Password.text
```

and now it works!

Comment: ` I tried this`  what exactly did you try?  See [Ask]

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. Try explaining what you need so a real answer can emerge.

Comment: You should be using a `DAL` Data Access layer. Should be a class where you pass that data to try to initialize the connection - then make queries.

Comment: You must use the Text property, correct code is uname = frmInstance.Username.Text.  Many more problems, trying to read the user name before he had a chance to enter it of course won't work.  Both you and us will greatly benefit from you spending time on a decent tutorial or introductory book on Windows Forms programming.  There are many.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is to create 2 public properties in your module.

```
Private _name As String

Public Property UserName() As String
    Get
        Return _username
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        _username = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then in your form, upon calling your module, you just need to pass the value to the module.

Comment: You don't initialize modules.

Comment: yep that's right, little typo while typing, thinking of Classes. :)

Comment: The OP appears to have what I would call a `DAL` layer and it should be a class and not a module at all. IMO